# np.where() with calculation consideration not working as intended

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Wrestling with this for some time today.
I'm trying to reset a column 'newMoneyValue' based on three other columns (valueA, valueB, valueC) such that:

- valueA > 0 and
- (valueB - valueC) is between -.1 and .1

If so, then set 'newMoneyValue' to 'oldMoneyValue' field, else set newMoneyValue to newMoneyValue, which currently is 0 for all rows.

My below code is resetting newMoneyValue to oldMoneyValue everywhere

```
df['newMoneyValue'] = np.where(
    df['valueA'] > 0 &
    ((df['valueB'] - df['valueC']) >= -.1) &
    ((df['valueB'] - df['valueC']) <= .1)
    ,df['oldMoneyValue']
    ,df['newMoneyValue'])
```

Comment: `(df['valueA'] > 0)`  missing ()

Comment: thx this was driving me crazy, but i see now how without the parenthesis I just wrote a fancy way of applying the logic to everything.